# Find the difference in years

Tags: postgresql

I need to find persons who works at least 40 years and then I need to upgrade their salary by 50% also after this I need to display their Personname, current date, and updated salary what should I do, I tried but program give me a error?

```
CREATE TABLE date_table (PERSONNAME text, JOBNAME text, HRDATE date, SALARY integer);
INSERT INTO date_table VALUES
('NAMEONE', 'JOBONE','23-APR-81', 1000), ('NAMETWO', 'JOBTWO', '16-JUN-81', 1000),
('NAMETHREE', 'JOBTHREE', '15-MAY-81', 1000), ('NAMEFOUR', 'JOBFOUR', '18-JUN-81', 1000),
('NAMEFIVE', 'JOBFIVE', '05-NOV-87', 1000), ('NAMESIX', 'JOBSIX', '28-FEB-81', 1000);

DO $$
DECLARE
answer text;
BEGIN
SELECT date_part ('17-NOV-81',HIREDATE) FROM empno_table;
END $$;
```

[image]

Comment: See `age()` here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-datetime.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Postgres has an `age()` function which will return the interval between its argument and `now()`

Check if the age is > 40 years:

```
select age('1981-01-02'::date)> interval '40 years';
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

Now use this in an update statement:

```
UPDATE date_table 
SET salary = (salary * 1.5)::integer 
WHERE age(hrdate)> interval '40 years';
```

Check result:

```
select * from date_table;
 personname | jobname  |   hrdate   | salary 
------------+----------+------------+--------
 NAMEONE    | JOBONE   | 1981-04-23 |   1000
 NAMETWO    | JOBTWO   | 1981-06-16 |   1000
 NAMETHREE  | JOBTHREE | 1981-05-15 |   1000
 NAMEFOUR   | JOBFOUR  | 1981-06-18 |   1000
 NAMEFIVE   | JOBFIVE  | 1987-11-05 |   1000
 NAMESIX    | JOBSIX   | 1981-02-28 |   1500
(6 rows)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it's really helps me, but but let me ask you another question, how to update hrdate to current date for people which work at least 40 years ?

Comment: See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-update.html - add `, hrdate = now()` to the `SET` clause.

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues with your select statement, causing the error message:

- `empno_table` does not exists in the scope of the example you posted
- `date_part` gets two parameters: 1) the part of the date you want to show, in your case `year`; and 2) date or date column
- `HIREDATE` is not an existing column in the example. It would be `HRDATE`.

Having this in mind, the following select statement will work:

```
SELECT date_part('year', HRDATE::date) FROM date_table;
```

Now, if you want to compare this date to the current date, you would use the `now()` like this:

```
SELECT date_part('year', now()::date) - date_part('year', HRDATE::date) FROM date_table;
```

This will give you the list of people who has been in the company for more than 40 years:

```
select * from (
    select *, date_part('year', now()::date) - date_part('year', HRDATE::date) as "YEARS_IN_COMPANY" 
    from date_table
  ) as date_table_with_years_in_company 
where "YEARS_IN_COMPANY" >= 40;
```

Comment: This will return a row if HRDATE is eg. `1981-12-01` and now is `2021-03-02` which is not correct.

Comment: Not according to the question before @blablabla edited it. Your solution is way better, though. No doubts about that. Voting up for yours.